# get Foreign Key field name by which inline form is related

Tags: django, django-admin

In django admin I have a ModelForm and an inline form. I need the name of the foreign key field in save_formset method by which model of inline form is related to model of main (parent) form.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    writer=models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

I need the field name ('writer' in this example) in save_formset method of ModelAdmin of Author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What exactly I guess , you are trying to get name of foreign key field related to particular modeladmin .

you should use save_formset fields in ModelAdmin , and find the foreign key name here.

```
all_formset_forms = formset.forms
```

This will return all inline forms of the current form you are trying to save.

Loop through each form fields and the fields you are asking for, i.e related foreign key field of a modeladmin instance is an attribute of parent_instance.

```
if hasattr(formset_form_field,'parent_instance'):
    formset_field_name  =  formset_form_field
    related_modeladmin_instance = formset_field_name.parent_instance
```